# Self-adjoint and isometric then $A^2=Id$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, isometry

If $E$ is a real vector space and $A:E\to E$ a linear operator self-adjoint and isometric (preserves inner product) then $A^2=Id$.

I think this problem is easy, but I think I'm missing something, could someone help me?

Comment: $A$ is isometric if and only if $A^{-1} = A^T$, then applying self-adjointness gets $A^2 = A A^T = A A^{-1} = I$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(\cdot, \cdot )$ the inner product. For $x \in E$ we have

$(A^2x-x, A^2x-x)=(A^2x,A^2x)-2(A^2x,x)+(x,x)=(Ax,Ax)-2(Ax,Ax)+(x,x)=-(Ax,Ax)+(x,x)=-(x,x)+(x,x)=0.$